# Telegram Bot: Commands visible for admin to use

Tags: python, flask, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Is there anyway that telegram bot can set commands that is available for administrator only? Because I wanted to implement a function that only admins of the telegram bot can use, not for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `python-telegram-bot` there are several ways to do that. A decorator as inyrface suggested can work - see also [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#restrict-access-to-a-handler-decorator) and [here for a way to cache the admins list](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#cached-telegram-group-administrator-check). Another option is to user [`Filters.user`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.user). Finally, [`ptbcontrib/roles`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/ptbcontrib/tree/main/ptbcontrib/roles) has a built-in cached admin check.

in addition to all of that, you can set up the commands such that in the gui they are only visible to admins - using [`BotCommandScopeChatAdministrators`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.botcommandscopechatadministrators.html). This doesn't prevent other users from manually typing the command, but's an additional step.

---

Disclaimer: I.m currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I managed to do it using the BotCommandScopeChatAdministrators.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper.

```
def restricted(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(update, context, *args, **kwargs):
        if not admin:
            return end_func(update, context, *args, **kwargs)

        return func(update, context, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped
```