# If condition and function in telegram bot script

Tags: python, bots, telegram, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I'm Working on a telegram bot,everything is good but I'm trying to display buttons for a specific user only, so i tried this:

```
def messageHandler(update:Update, context: CallbackContext):
    t = update.message.chat_id
    if t == <desired user id> :
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Welcome back admin", reply_markup =ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))
        
        if FirstButton in update.message.text:
            
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='Edit1 is working')
       
        if SecondButton in update.message.text:
            
             context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Edit2 is wo

    rking")
        else:
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text ="NOT ADMIN!!!!!")
```

**but i want to start a function so i did this:**

```
def Control(x):
    if x == <desired user id>:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Welcome back admin", reply_markup =ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))
        
        if FirstButton in update.message.text:
            
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='Edit1 is working')
       
        if SecondButton in update.message.text:
            
             context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Edit2 is working")
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text ="NOT ADMIN!!!!!")
```

**and I'm calling it using**

```
def messageHandler(update:Update, context: CallbackContext):
    t = update.message.chat_id
    Control(t)
```

**but it does not work
anyone can help me?**

Comment: You're using `update` in `Control`, so you should also pass it to that function. Not sure why you'd need another function though

Comment: @RJAdriaansen i tried your solution but i didn't work. how can i do it without another function, without effecting other tasks for users ( my aim is to do admin keyboard), can you help me with any ideas?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433967/11380795

Answer (score 0):

Try Using a commmand for admin task, add  if condition into it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).